# Convert Java Class into Kotlin Class using Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, kotlin

I'm trying to convert a java class into Kotlin using eclipse Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2) but it is not working.

[image]

When I click on "**Convert Java to Kotlin**" nothing is returned in the console and nothing is happening.

I do have the Kotlin plugin and I'm able to create Kotlin classes and compile my code. So far everything is working fine but the conversion.

Comment: I think you'll find that the Eclipse plugin is not very well maintained. JetBrains is hoping to get everyone to use their IntelliJ IDEA for Kotlin development - and the community edition of it is free to use.

Comment: Does this mean that it's recommended to drop Eclipse usage as an IDE for Kotlin and switch to IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: If you can do that, yes, that's what will get you the smoothest Kotlin experience.

Comment: or you can use the Convert from Java button online on https://try.kotlinlang.org

Comment: I've seen issues with Intellij IDEA's converter as well. But still it's much better than eclipse right now, and for all practical reasons might continue to be (given JetBrain is the creator of Kotlin). So yes, I guess, better to switch to Intellij IDEA for Kotlin.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse's Kotlin integration is not as great as IntelliJ-based IDE's right now, Bu if you don't want to switch to their IDEs, you could always use Kotlin's online Java-to-Kotlin [here](https://try.kotlinlang.org) and use the top-right button.